# NO BOOTABLE DEVICE | NO ACTIVE PARTITION | Acer | Windows10 Home

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

Note : I know there are some similar question like this but my problem is somewhat different. please take a look.

So let me tell the truth. I had tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 along side windows as a dual boot system. i have done it before many times but this time was my bad luck and something gone wrong.

after restarting i have welcomed with windows 10, i repeated this 2  -  3 times then searched on internet for the strange issue and got some results like grub menu is not properly installed and all. then i followed a tutorial and ran ubuntu through a LiveDVD and fired those command and nothing happened. then i again turned off my laptop and started it again and voilla.

NO BOOTABLE DEVICE. **BOOM**. what just happened why in the name of holy god that happened to me i missed playing my game Dota2 just because of this issue. i tried too much many commands and tutorial around the web showing similiar issue and its resolution but any of then never worked for me.

So can you guyz please help me.

NOTE : i probably have done ubuntu installtion in bad manner this time and i didn't turned off the fast boot and did not disabled secure boot before ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the BIOS from EUFI to Legacy? That could be one reason.

Or during the installation you might have overwritten the partition that Windows creates and hence it is not starting. Change the BIOS settings to what it was before and try startup repair using Windows 10 DVD.

Worst case scenario, you can use a Live CD to take a backup of your data and reformat the drive and reinstall Windows 10 + Unbuntu with secure boot disabled and BIOS set to Legacy.

Comment: yes i tried changing to Legacy but then it was showing "NO Active Partition".

Comment: "startup repair using Windows 10 DVD" this i am gonna try today. hope it helped. But tell me one thing is this needful to change BIOS to legacy if i want to install ubuntu as dual boot.

Comment: Depends on whether Ubuntu support EUFI. Check Ubuntu documentation

Comment: i got this. i backed up all my data fully reset the PC. btw thanks.

Comment: **Ubuntu supports UEFI and should be installed in UEFI mode in any UEFI machine.** And you definitely need to understand UEFI before attempting the dual boot. What you know from before (BIOS) is of little to no use in modern machines. This is a very nice guide for dual booting in UEFI mode: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi